# ASP.net Server Error/Parser Error

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a strange problem with my asp.net website.
I want to run it on two different servers. On one server there is no problem at all but on the other i get the following error message when trying to open it with chrome or ie.

> Server Error in '/RTA/ETO' Application.
>
> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message:
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCellCollection must have items of
>   type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell'. 'asp:TextBox' is of
>   type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 170:                   Line 171:                     Line 172:
>   
>   Text="" ValidationGroup="Size" Visible = 'false' Width="100%"
>   TabIndex="4" > Line 174:

the code:

```
<tr id="tr_customerMarketOrganization" runat="server">
                <td align="left" colspan="1" valign="top" class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:Label ID="L_CustomerMarketOrganization" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="1em" 
                        ForeColor="#14007F"></asp:Label>
                </td> 
                <td align="left"; class="style19">
                  **here ist line 172**  <asp:TextBox ID="tbCustomer" runat="server" 
                        Text="" ValidationGroup="Size" Visible = 'false' Width="100%" TabIndex="4" ></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Label ID="L_Error_Customer" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="Red" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Source File: /RTA/Konfigurator_ETO/default.aspx    Line: 172

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.19028

Comment: It very hard to tell just by looking at the exception alone, maybe sharing the html code as well could make finding a solution.

Comment: the thing is on the other server everything works fine

Comment: I get that but you still the show the code so that SO's can easily spot what could potentially be the reason for this.

Comment: code is visibile now

Comment: i think there is either a problem with the webconfig or something went wrong when uploading the files to the server, i try to fix it

Comment: Looking at the code,  all seems well. Though I'm not an IIS expert but it could happen that there's a difference in IIS settings between the two servers. i.e. Compare the application pools. Also see if changing Visible = 'false' to Visible = "False" won't make a difference. That's my 2 cent :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by simply reupload the files on the server. So the code wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No idea about why this error occurs but i had this issue too, just i restart my system and run the application, it work fine now.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @RahulSingh I don't have enough Reputations to Comment here, it needs at-least 50 Reputations, that is why is have placed as an answer, make Sense?

Comment: for me it's no problem. i have updated the webconfig file for the other server maybe it will work then, but i have to wait

Comment: @Arturka1 Okay, if it does work then can you please share the solution, so that can be helpful to other as well.

Comment: @ChiragThakar - No, if you don't have enough reputation then better wait for that, it not at all recommended to post an answer. BTW I am not the downvoter.

Comment: @RahulSingh Thanks again, I didn't have Idea about that, Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This is a parsing error. There are single quotes that need to be double quotes around `Visible = 'false'` --> `Visible = "false"`.